# manipulating array: adding number of occurrences to the duplicate elements

Tags: ruby, erb

(You are welcome to change the title to a more appropriate one!)

I got another Ruby/ERB question. I have this file:

```
ec2-23-22-59-32, mongoc, i-b8b44, instnum=1, Running
ec2-54-27-11-46, mongod, i-43f9f, instnum=2, Running
ec2-78-62-192-20, mongod, i-02fa4, instnum=3, Running
ec2-24-47-51-23, mongos, i-546c4, instnum=4, Running
ec2-72-95-64-22, mongos, i-5d634, instnum=5, Running
ec2-27-22-219-75, mongoc, i-02fa6, instnum=6, Running
```

And I can process the file to create an array like this:

```
irb(main):007:0> open(inFile).each { |ln| puts ln.split(',').map(&:strip)[0..1] }
ec2-23-22-59-32
mongoc
ec2-54-27-11-46
mongod
....
....
```

But what I really want is the *occurrence number* concatenated to the *"mongo-type"* so that it becomes:

```
ec2-23-22-59-32
mongoc1
ec2-54-27-11-46
mongod1
ec2-78-62-192-20
mongod2
ec2-24-47-51-23
mongos1
ec2-72-95-64-22
mongos2
ec2-27-22-219-75
mongoc2
```

The number of each mongo-type is not fixed and it changes over time. Any help with how can I do that? Thanks in advance. Cheers!!

Comment: How do you define "occurrence number"? Is it in the file or calculated? Would it be sufficient for your purposes to append the instance number?

Comment: @Mark: The value should be calculated. Say, if there is three entry for mongod in the file, then I should have `mongod1`, `mongod2`, `mongod3` and the same rule should be applied to other Mongo instances as well. The number of MongoC, MongoD and MongoS varies in the file, based on users' decision when they spin up the VMs and the file is generated automatically based on their requirement. Does it answer to your question? cheers!!

Comment: @Mark: w.r.t. your last question, appending the "instance number" to the "mongo" is not the thing I'm really looking for but I like to see hoe to do it. I may use that for some other purpose. Cheers!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick answer (maybe could be optimized):

```
data = 'ec2-23-22-59-32, mongoc, i-b8b44, instnum=1, Running
ec2-54-27-11-46, mongod, i-43f9f, instnum=2, Running
ec2-78-62-192-20, mongod, i-02fa4, instnum=3, Running
ec2-24-47-51-23, mongos, i-546c4, instnum=4, Running
ec2-72-95-64-22, mongos, i-5d634, instnum=5, Running
ec2-27-22-219-75, mongoc, i-02fa6, instnum=6, Running'

# a hash where we will save mongo types strings as keys
# and number of occurence as values
mtypes = {}
data.lines.each do |ln|
  # get first and second element of given string to inst and mtype respectively
  inst, mtype = ln.split(',').map(&:strip)[0..1]
  # check if mtypes hash has a key that equ current mtype
  # if yes -> add 1 to current number of occurence
  # if not -> create new key and assign 1 as a value to it
  # this is a if ? true : false -- ternary operator
  mtypes[mtype] = mtypes.has_key?(mtype) ? mtypes[mtype] + 1 : 1
  # combine an output string (everything in #{ } is a variables
  # so #{mtype}#{mtypes[mtype]} means take current value of mtype and
  # place after it current number of occurence stored into mtypes hash
  p "#{inst} : #{mtype}#{mtypes[mtype]}"
end
```

Output:

```
# "ec2-23-22-59-32 : mongoc1"
# "ec2-54-27-11-46 : mongod1"
# "ec2-78-62-192-20 : mongod2"
# "ec2-24-47-51-23 : mongos1"
# "ec2-72-95-64-22 : mongos2"
# "ec2-27-22-219-75 : mongoc2"
```

Quite strightforward I think. If you don't understand something -- let me know.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked just fine. I think I understood most of it but can you explain the 4th line where the value is being calculated pls? Cheers!!